# list index out of range error with Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, bioinformatics

I have the above code as part of a bigger code to do some parsing and a little bit more. Whenever I run the code I get the following error message "list index out of range". I printed the **folder** so I see them, and I get the following print:

> "**velvet_results2/velvet_results_assembly/my_sample_velvet**

".
 and within my_sample_velvet folder is the xml file I need to parse. Can anyone help me to solve this problem, please?

```
matches_counts={}
velvet_folders = glob.glob(velvet_output +'/*')
for folder in velvet_folders:
    print folder
    xml_file=glob.glob(folder + '/*.xml')[0]
    matches = parsing_blast(xml_file,opts.length_cutoff)
```

Comment: post your full stack trace

Comment: `glob.glob(folder + '/*.xml')` is empty, it's not finding any .xml files

Comment: It seems like `folder` doesn't contain the .xml files, they're within sub-directories inside this, so you need to `glob` on those

Comment: My xml_file is within the my_sample_velvet. That is why when I glob.glob(floder + '/ *.xml')

Comment: Traceback Please!

Comment: #Chris_Rands, I think I found the problem but I don't know how to solve it. I printed xml_file, and I found that it also get one txt file that is in that folder.                                 
  **velvet_results2/velvet_results_assembly/my sample1_velvet/blast_file.xml                                                                     
velvet_results2/velvet_results_assembly/my_gene_extraction.txt**

Comment: Ubdus Samad- it was a traceback, there was an index error, the one I explained in the tittle. I have just modified the code, and I got the script working. I was only a question of adding and '/' in the first glob.glob event.

Comment: Post your corrected code as an answer instead of fixing your question code. Otherwise your question makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
matches_counts={}
velvet_folders = glob.glob(velvet_output +'/*/')
for folder in velvet_folders:
    print folder
    xml_file=glob.glob(folder + '/*.xml')[0]
    matches = parsing_blast(xml_file,opts.length_cutoff)
```

By adding the second '/' in the velvet_folder line I solved the problem.